# Double values being inserted

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

`$categories` result before the foreach loop -

`array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2"}`

`$categories` result within the foreach loop -

```
string(1) "1"string(1) "1"string(1) "2"string(1) "2"
```

`$sortOrder` result before the foreach loop -

`array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "20" [1]=> string(2) "13" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) ""}`

`$sortOrder` result within the foreach loop -

```
string(2) "20"string(2) "13"string(0) ""string(0) ""string(2) "20"string(2) "13"string(0) ""string(0) ""
```

Why am I getting double values once in the foreach?

```
foreach($categories as $cat)
{
    foreach($sortOrder as $sort)
    {
        if(strlen($sort)>0)
        {
            //$this->Ps_products_model->brand_by_category_insert($brand_name,$brand_id,$cat,$sort,$state);
        }
    }
}
$this->load->view('admin/ajax/test', $data);
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Cat: 1, Sort: 20 
Cat: 2, Sort: 13
```

Comment: Can you provide output of what your intended results are?

Comment: @Crackertastic I am basically wanting like the first arrays are and the "singular" results and not the "double" values

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? The outer foreach runs twice, because you have two entries in $categories. So the whole $sortOrder foreach runs twice. So if you're printing out var_dump($sort) or something like that (can't tell), you're going to get everything twice. I'm sure I don't understand the question.

Comment: @matt  I am trying to get it to insert the $categories and $sortOrder with one set of data instead of the double up.  How could I get it to insert once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if i am a little confused on what exactly you are trying to achieve, but when i run the following (based on your code):

```
<?php

$categories = array("1", "2");
$sortOrder = array("20", "13", "", "");
echo '<pre>';

foreach($categories as $cat) {
    foreach($sortOrder as $sort) {
        if(strlen($sort) > 0 ) {
            print("Cat: $cat, Sort: $sort \n");
        }
    }
}

echo '</pre>';

?>
```

I get the followimg:

```
Cat: 1, Sort: 20 
Cat: 1, Sort: 13 
Cat: 2, Sort: 20 
Cat: 2, Sort: 13
```

So what exactly are you expecting for results?  Could you provide some sample output please?

EDIT:

In that case what you need is a for loop:

```
<?php 
    $categories = array("1", "2");
    $sortOrder = array("20", "13", "", "");
    echo '<pre>';

    for($i = 0; $i < count($categories); $i++) {
        print("Cat: $categories[$i], Sort: $sortOrder[$i] \n");
    }

    echo '</pre>';

 ?>
```

Will get you:

```
Cat: 1, Sort: 20 
Cat: 2, Sort: 13
```

Answer (score 1):

(Just in case Crackertastic doesn't get back to it.) I'm assuming what you mean is that the first element of $categories matches up with the first element of $sortOrder, and so on? Then I think you want something like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($categories); $i++) {
    $cat = $categories[$i];
    $sort = $sortOrder[$i];
    print("Cat: $cat, Sort: $sort \n");
}
```

But this will break down if $categories has more entries than $sortOrder. Maybe you are handling that elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Matt, Would this remove the need for the foreach?  It should not have more entries as there is only an $sort input box for each $cat

Comment: Yes, just use the for loop.

Comment: Thanks Matt wish I could accept you both - has had me stumped for awhile

Comment: Glad you accepted crackertastic, as his initial answer was really what sussed out the problem. :-)